# Python glob.glob function not executing

Tags: python, glob

Can someone please tell me why my glob.glob statement is not executing?

I have written one that works fine, but the other one does not work. Can you see what i am doing wrong.

I am using pycharm.

This one works

```
TC = glob.glob("L:/Support/Data_load/Tenements/%s/NSW/FME*/GSNSWDataset/TitlesCurrent.shp" % (d))[0]

x = arcpy.AddField_management(TC, "Date_Ext", "DATE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

This one does not. I have now added [0] to the end as suggested but now i just get this error instead " IndexError: list index out of range"

```
Moo = glob.glob(r"L:\Support\Data_load\Tenements\{}\SA\Mineral tenements - exploration\Exploration Licence Applications-Mineral and_or Opal_*\Exploration Licence Applications-Mineral and_or Opal.gdb\Mineral_and_or_Opal_Exploration_Licence_Applications")[0]

# Process: Add Field
X = arcpy.AddField_management(Moo,'Test2',"TEXT","","",100)
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not executing?

Comment: In the first code you're selecting the first file returned with `[0]`. The second one doesn't do this, so you're trying to pass the entire list to `AddField_management`.

Comment: Hi Barmar i get this error "RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool"

Comment: @Barmar oh my, i put [0] on the end and it works. Thank you. I am new to python, and the previous code was copied. If i want to find out more about [0] and how this stuff works do you know what i should look up? Thanks again

Comment: Any python tutorial will tell you what `[0]` means.

Comment: `glob.glob()` returns a list of all the matching files. `somelist[0]` returns the first element of a list.

Comment: @Barmar thank i will do a bit more research :). I have noticed however that putting [0] works for the shapefile but not the geodatabase. instead i am getting an error when my path file is to the geodatabase. . IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If there are no matches, it will return an empty list. You can't extract the first element if there are no elements.

Comment: You can't program by cutting and pasting code you don't understand. You need to learn the basics.

Comment: @ Barmar isn't the feature class within the geodatabse an element. ?

Comment: `glob.glob()` has nothing to do with the geodatabase. It just returns filenames that match a wildcard pattern. If there are no matching files, it returns an empty list.